# how to add a color selector to my drawing app

Tags: javascript, html

In my drawing app I can only have certain colors that I have put in but I want to have a color picker like [this one](http://www.colorpicker.com/), I have already tried to just add loads of colors but it gets too much and overlaps my toolbar.

```
<div id="colors">
    <div class="swatch active" style="background-color: black"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: grey"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: orange"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: indigo"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: violet"></div>
    <div class="swatch" style="background-color: #FF0080"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daniel9000/egpr99k9/8/). Please relate to my code so it will definitely work.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
 — don't edit the question text to say it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a plugin.

This one looks promising http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about

Your code could be like the example one on the page

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

Here is more instructions on getting the plugin working http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#implement

Comment: This plugin requires jQuery you would need to include the jQuery file as well. Make sure you are including the files at the top of your html and that the files are in the right spot relative to each other.